# Tensorflow distribute `OneDeviceStrategy` still partially fills other GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am experimenting with the distributed strategies of tensorflow, `MirroredStrategy` and `OneDeviceStrategy`. As I understand, `OneDeviceStrategy` should behave pretty much like not using a strategy at all, and just running on a single GPU. However, upon running my code using `OneDeviceStrategy` I noticed that, while I pick 1 of my 4 gpus to perform the computation, part of the memory of the remaining gpus is also filled. While I am setting GPU 2 to be used with `OneDeviceStrategy`, GPU 1 and 3 end up with about 550MB filled, while GPU 0 ends up with about 680MB filled. The amount of GPU 0 filled seems to depend on the batch size I use. I did check if it was the training script that was filling this memory, and it was in fact, since stopping the script also emptied out the memory in those 3 gpus. Is there any reason for that?

For the record I followed the guide at https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/ for distributed training, testing with both `MirroredStrategy`, and `OneDeviceStrategy`.